# Why is "var" a legal type name in C#?

Tags: c#, var

[As it turns out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables#remarks), you can create a class named `var` and instantiate it with `new var();`. What influenced the C# developers to allow this to happen with `var` but not other keywords?

Answer (score 10):

`var` was only introduced in C# 3.0. It wasn't a keyword at all in older versions of the language. The designers presumably didn't anticipate creating a `var` keyword at the time they first designed the language, so code was always allowed to use it as an identifier.

That's why `var` is only a contextual keyword. If it were made a reserved word, existing code would break in the C# 3.0 compiler until all occurrences of `var` were renamed.

Comment: as he said, var does not represent anything aside of implicit type

Comment: Was there a precedent with other keywords which disallowed previously valid type names from being used?

Comment: @user1306322 - you can also have variables called e.g. `async`. Basically, any new keywords added after C# 1 tend to be contextual. Can't think of any that aren't.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/#contextual-keywords